# Determine if following big matrix $M$ is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra

I have following big matrix

$$
M:=\left(\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
A & M_1 & M_2 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
0 & D_1 & D_2 & * &\ldots & \ldots & * \\ \hline
\vdots & D_3 & D_4 & * & \ldots & \ldots & * \\ \hline
\vdots & 0 & H_1 & F_1 & 0 &\ldots & 0 \\ \hline
\vdots & \vdots & H_2 & * & F_2 & 0 & 0  \\ \hline
\vdots & \vdots & 0 & * & * & \ddots & 0 \\ \hline
0 &0 &0 & * & * &* &F_{n-2}
\end{array}\right)
$$

Ultimately, I want to show, that $M$ is invertible.

I have following information: $A$ is invertible and $D_1$ is a diagonal matrix and therefore invertible, too. $F_1,\ldots, F_{n-2}$ are diagonal matrices, such that

$$
L:=\left(\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
F_1 & 0 &\ldots & 0 \\ \hline
* & F_2 & 0 & 0  \\ \hline
* & * & \ddots & 0 \\ \hline
* & * &* &F_{n-2}
\end{array}\right)
$$

is an invertible lower diagonal matrix.

Now, I wonder, if it is enough to show, that
$$
\left(\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
D_1 & D_2 \\ \hline
D_3 & D_4 \\ 
\end{array}\right)
$$

or $D_4$ are invertible, such that $M$ is invertible. Is this true or a naive thought?

I basically wonder, how I have to handle the "middle" part, meaning the columns

$$
M:=\left(\begin{array}{c|c}
M_1 & M_2  \\ \hline
D_1 & D_2  \\ \hline
D_3 & D_4  \\ \hline
0 & H_1 &  \\ \hline
\vdots & H_2 \\ \hline
\vdots & 0 \\ \hline
0 &0 
\end{array}\right)
$$

to show that $M$ is invertible.

Thank you in advance for any hint or help!

**EDIT:** Ok, so far, my idea is following: I use the first column to get rid of $M_1$ and $M_2$ in the first row:

$$
M:=\left(\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
A & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
0 & D_1 & D_2 & * &\ldots & \ldots & * \\ \hline
0 & D_3 & D_4 & * & \ldots & \ldots & * \\ \hline
0 & 0 & H_1 & F_1 & 0 &\ldots & 0 \\ \hline
0 & \vdots & H_2 & * & F_2 & 0 & 0  \\ \hline
0 & \vdots & 0 & * & * & \ddots & 0 \\ \hline
0 &0 &0 & * & * &* &F_{n-2}
\end{array}\right)
$$

Then I'm going to use the second column to eliminate all the rest in the second row:

$$
M:=\left(\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
A & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
0 & D_1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
0 & D_3 & * & * & \ldots & \ldots & * \\ \hline
0 & 0 & H_1 & F_1 & 0 &\ldots & 0 \\ \hline
0 & 0 & H_2 & * & F_2 & 0 & 0  \\ \hline
0 & 0 & 0 & * & * & \ddots & 0 \\ \hline
0 &0 &0 & * & * &* &F_{n-2}
\end{array}\right)
$$

Now, going backwards I use $F_{n-2},\ldots,F_1$ one after the other to get rid of the zeros in the last $n-2$ rows:

$$
M:=\left(\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
A & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
0 & D_1 & 0 & 0 &0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
0 & D_3 & * & * & \ldots & \ldots & * \\ \hline
0 & 0 & 0 & F_1 & 0 &\ldots & 0 \\ \hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & F_2 & 0 & 0  \\ \hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ddots & 0 \\ \hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 &F_{n-2}
\end{array}\right)
$$

Now, if this middle part

$$\left(\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
 D_1 & 0 \\ \hline
 D_3 & *  \\ 
\end{array}\right)
$$

would be invertible, I would be done, right? But in $*$ have already gone in a lot of calculations. Is there a way around this?

Comment: I think I have to work with the Schur complement, again. First show that $\begin{pmatrix} D_1 & D_2\\ D_3 & D_4\end{pmatrix}$ is invertible and work with the blocks below and right to it?

Comment: The $D$-matrix being invertible isn't enough: it's possible, for example, that the sum of the second and third "rows" of the block matrix equals the fourth "row".

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't even get basic ideas, how I could reduce anything. Even not a simple one. Would I just need to swap columns and rows?

Comment: The down right matrix, with $F_3, \ldots, F_{n-2}$ would be a lower triangular matrix and invertible, too. Could I use that, somehow?